# How can I establish whether my network chip is failing?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, thinkpad

In the middle of a Skype call yesterday, my friend told me my framerate and audio had abruptly dropped to broken and unusable levels. I could still see and hear him perfectly. Instant messaging works perfectly, but with voice chat over Steam I can hear perfectly but not be heard.

I am unable to play networked video games whatsoever-- the pings with other players are in the 6000s.

In general it seems webpages load perfectly.

I restored the computer to a backup from a week prior: same problem. I reinstalled/updated network drivers: nothing. I ran a virus scan: nothing.

The problem seems to be with outbound traffic, yet it only seems to apply to "stream-y" type things.

I can't think what else could be wrong other than a failing network chip. Is there any way to be sure?

Note, this is over wifi. I have no LAN cables to test with.
Also, my other laptop, a mac, works perfectly. Issue does not seem to be with my internet.

Comment: If you have Wi-Fi in your place then the LAN cable is connected to your router/access point/switch/GPON station or whatever. Otherwise I don't see a option on how would you have Wi-Fi without any cables. Try to connect the exact same cable to the laptop RJ-45 jack of yours and see if the issue stays the same.

Comment: There is only a single axial cable.

Comment: Does your networking gear have a slot for any of a CAT series cables? Do you have any of spare CAT cables? Have you tried to make a network bridge with your mac?

Comment: Does your other laptop have the same type of wifi as this machine? If, for example, the mac has 802.11n on 5GHz and the computer with the issue only has 802.11g on 2.4GHz, that could well explain it.

Answer (score 0):

> the pings with other players are in the 6000s.

Do you mean 6000ms? Please try to run the traceroute on your OS so that you will find which hop causes so high latency.

If the first hop causes it, it means that your laptop has connection issues with the WIFI router.

Comment: Sorry, noob question, but who should I traceroute with? Does it not matter? Google.com?

Comment: You should trace the target which has a high latency.